# Random Number Generator in C

Tags: c, random

I'm trying to generate a random number 0 - 59, and am not satisfied with the rand() function in C. Here is the code I'm playing around with:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

main()
{

int num;
srand(time(NULL));
num = rand();
num = num % 59;
printf("%d\n", num);
}
```

I've repeated the run on this code and noticed that the random numbers being generated don't really seem that random. The generated numbers produced are definitely following a pattern, as each time I run the program the number gets progressively larger until it wraps back around to the beginning (i.e. 2, 17, 21, 29, 38, 47, 54, 59, 4, 11....etc).

Is there a way I can seed the function so that every time I re-run the function I get a true random number with a 1/60 chance of being generated? Or are there any alternative methods I can implement myself rather than using the rand() function in C?

Comment: Where is `#include <stdio.h>` ?

Comment: Don't use `%` to restrict the range of pseudo-random numbers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984974/why-do-people-say-there-is-modulo-bias-when-using-a-random-number-generator

Comment: Here is another way to generate your numbers, that seems to match your need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14441680/is-it-modern-c-to-use-srand-to-set-random-seed

Comment: Don't try to implement your own generator.  Assuming this is for statistical purposes rather than crypto, do a google search for "Mersenne Twister".

Comment: @pjs thanks for the heads up on the Mersenne Twister

Comment: Generating a single random number from each of a variety of seeds is essentially testing the randomness of your seed sequence, not the PRNG. Changing the PRNG will not change the seed sequence or its entropy.

Answer (score 7):

> Is there a way I can seed the function so that every time I re-run the function I get a true random number

No, the C standard library uses a PRNG (pseudorandom number generator). You will never get **true** random numbers.

You can, however, seed it with something that changes more frequently than `time()`, for example, on POSIX:

```
struct timeval tm;
gettimeofday(&tm, NULL);
srandom(tm.tv_sec + tm.tv_usec * 1000000ul);
```

Also, using the modulo operator for generating a random number is not a good solution (it severely decreases entropy). If you have a BSD-style libc implementation, use

```
uint32_t n = arc4random_uniform(60);
```

Or, if you don't have this function:

```
// random() is guaranteed to return a number in the range [0 ... 2 ** 31)
#define MAX_RANDOM ((1 << 31) - 1)

long n;

do {
    n = random();
} while (n > (MAX_RANDOM - ((MAX_RANDOM % 60) + 1) % 60));
n %= 60;
```

Note the use of `random()` - it is superior to `rand()` (which had and has a number of low-quality implementations). This function can be seeded using `srandom()`.

> Or are there any alternative methods I can implement myself rather than using the rand() function in C?

You can (of course, else how would the writers of the C library implementation do it?), but you better not - it's a separate science to write a good PRNG, so to say.

Comment: The fundamental problem with `%` is that it tries to fit 2**n equiprobable beads into 60 buckets. How is `rand() / (double)RAND_MAX * 60` any better?

Comment: @PascalCuoq Is it not? If you use modulo division, the chance of getting numbers between 0 and `60 - (2 ** n % 60)` is higher. AFAIK this problem is not present when you exclude the modulus operation, since the problem is caused by the fact that `2 ** n` may not be divisible by 60.

Comment: Well, the fact that `2 ** n` is not divisible by 60 is exactly the problem, and with `/ (double)RAND_MAX * 60` you are still sending these `2 ** n` equiprobable values to 60 buckets in a deterministic way. It is not the same buckets that get more beads, but mathematically, some buckets still get more beads.

Comment: @PascalCuoq So did I just run into [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984974/why-do-people-say-there-is-modulo-bias-when-using-a-random-number-generator#comment14490185_10989061)? (If so, I'm editing my answer.)

Comment: Yes. If you get beads 2**n at a time, the only way to fill 60 buckets equally is to either throw away some beads, or to request another set of 2**n beads, or a mix of both these actions.

Comment: @PascalCuoq Edited, I hope it's good now.

Comment: It doesn't set `n` to a number below 60. Try `long N = MAX_RANDOM / 60; do { n = random() / N ; } while (n >= 60);` (untested)

Comment: @PascalCuoq Sorry, I don't understand, now what's the problem?

Comment: With the current code, `n` is not set to a value in the interval 0-59. That was the original question.

Comment: @sh1 What do you suggest instead?

Comment: @PascalCuoq Ah, I see. I forgot the modulus.

Answer (score 1):

The way your program is written, you must re-run it each time to get a new random number,  which also means it gets re-seeded each time.  Re-seeding a PRNG is *bad*.

You want to seed **once**, then generate a bunch of random numbers.

Do it this way:

```
int main(void)
{
    int num, i;
    srand(time(NULL));  // Seed ONCE

    for(i=0; i<100; ++i) // Loop 100 times for random numbers
    {
        num = rand();
        num = num % 59;
        printf("%d\n", num);
    }
}
```

Now you should get much better results.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you re-run the program, you re-seed with `time()`, and that function only advances once a second (if you re-run the program quickly enough you'll get the same result).

The fact that it seems to increment until it rolls over suggests that the first call to `rand()` is returning the un-modified seed -- that number which increments once per second.  In that case you're getting the same results (or very similar results) as if you'd run:

```
printf("%d\n", time(NULL) % 59);
```

I'm sure you can see what's wrong with that.

In this case, if you used the 'more correct' `rand() * 59 / RAND_MAX`, which is meant to prefer a value from the 'more random' bits, you would have an even worse situation -- the results wouldn't change at all for maybe 500 seconds, or more.

Fundamentally you need to find a less predictable seed, but you may also want to see that it's properly mixed before you use it.

Reading from `/dev/urandom` should provide a good seed, in which case you won't need to worry about mixing, but otherwise calling `rand()` a couple of times should help to do away with the especially glaring artefacts of the low-quality seed you started with (except, of course, the problem that it only changes once a second).