# Random number generator of any length

Tags: c, random

How to generate any random number of any width in C?? Like, to generate a number of width 3 it should be between 100 to 999. So how to code this?

Comment: Look at the `srand` and `rand` functions.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18254325/random-number-generator-in-c

Comment: Show what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can use rand() function. I hope with this can help you [Random Number](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_rand.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`rand()`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_rand.htm) function .
It returns value between `0` to `RAND_MAX`.

To get a random number between a range you can write like this -

```
  int r;
  r= rand()%901+100;
```

This will give a random number between `100` and `1000`.