# Why are std::shuffle methods being deprecated in C++14?

Tags: c++, c++11, deprecated, c++14, stl-algorithm

According to the [cppreference.com](http://cppreference.com) reference site on [std::shufle](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle), the following method is being deprecated in c++14:

```
template< class RandomIt >
void random_shuffle( RandomIt first, RandomIt last );
```

Why will we no longer be able to call the following function without passing a third parameter?

```
std::random_shuffle(v.begin(),v.end()); //no longer valid in c++14
```

It doesn't appear as though a different function deceleration has a default parameter set.  What is the reason behind this?  Was there some kind of alternative added?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

`std::random_shuffle` *may* make use, under the hood, of `random` C family of functions. These functions use global state for seeds and other state.

So it is being deprecated because `shuffle` will do the same, but better. Namely, it uses the new `<random>` header from C++11 that doesn't use global state, but its own objects making use of generators, devices and distributions.

Comment: `std::random_shuffle` **may** use `rand`.  It is not *required* to use `rand`.  Some implementations do, and some do not.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I was mistaken there. Sorry for this inaccuracy.

Comment: What is wrong with using a global state? In fact that is much better than creating a new pseudo random generator every time, which will then always provide you with the same values.

Answer (score 48):

`std::random_shuffle` is (effectively) replaced by `std::shuffle`. You do need to pass a third parameter (a random number generator), but in exchange for that you get substantially better definition and (typically) behavior.

`std::random_shuffle` was fairly poorly defined. It typically used `rand()` to generate the random numbers, but nothing said whether (and if so how) it called `srand`, so you couldn't depend (for one example) in `rand` being seeded how you wanted (and if you seeded it, you couldn't depend on that being put to use). If memory serves, there was also some confusing (and somewhat self-contradictory) language that could be interpreted as saying that `random_shuffle` couldn't use `rand` at all, and/or that it couldn't seed it with `srand`. Even at best, many implementations of `rand()` were quite poor, so even at very best you couldn't depend on useful results.

Bottom line: `random_shuffle` is no loss. Use `std::shuffle` instead, and your code will be much better for it.

Comment: There seems to be a second overload that accepts an RNG though... is that one fine to use?

Comment: @Mehrdad: I believe so, yes. It's basically equivalent to `std::shuffle`. I don't see any real reason to prefer it over `std::shuffle` though.

Comment: The `RandomNumberGenerator` in `random_shuffle` has a different API than the `UniformRandomNumberGenerator` in `shuffle` does.  The latter has an API consistent with the Uniform random number generator requirements in [rand.req.urng].  The former has an API specified only in the requires clause of `random_shuffle`.

Comment: "so you couldn't depend (for one example) in rand being seeded how you wanted (and if you seeded it, you couldn't depend on that being put to use)" Why is that an issue? Its purpose is to generate random numbers. Of course you shouldn't depend on what is supposed to be random numbers.

Comment: `std::shuffle` is *worse* because you have to explicitly provide a specific algorithm, and most programmers aren't the best at choosing one - this task is much better left to the implementers. Also if you explicitly provide one, even if it's good, that means that it can't ever be changed to something better. If you don't provide one, then it could always be changed to something better.

Comment: @Neme: For things like testing, repeatability is often important, so even though the order is "random", being able to reproduce the same order is extremely useful. In theory, it might be better to leave things up to an implementer, but in fact `rand` is so often so bad that even if you choose poorly, it'll almost always be better.

Comment: @JerryCoffin For testing, you should mock a random number generator.

Comment: @Neme: For testing, you should use a pseudo-random number generator, and give it a known seed. And with a sane shuffle, you can do exactly that, with no difficulty at all.

Answer (score 16):

We can find the rationale in this document [N3775: Deprecating rand and Friends](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3775.pdf) which says:

> We therefore now propose to execute the next step of this plan to discourage the use of the
>   traditional C function rand as well as its associated seeding function srand and upper limit macro
>   RAND_MAX.<sup>6</sup> In particular, we propose to begin this transition by formally deprecating:
>
> - rand, srand, and RAND_MAX and
> - algorithm random_shuffle() (keeping shuffle, however).
>
> The rationale for deprecating random_shuffle() is that one overload is specified so as to depend
>   on rand, while the other overload is specified so as to require a hard-to-produce distribution
>   object from the user; such a distribution is already an implicit part of shuffle, which we retain.

and the later document [Discouraging rand() in C++14, v2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3924.pdf) which reiterates this position.

**Update**

As Howard Hinnant notes `N3775` has an error: `rand_shuffle()` is allowed but not required to use `rand()` under the hood but that would not change the rationale.

Comment: N3775 is in error in saying that `rand_shuffle()` is specified so as to depend on `rand`.  It is correct to say that it is allowed to be implemented on top of `rand`.  But it is not required to be implemented on top of `rand`.

Comment: @HowardHinnant Thank you for pointing that out, I was wondering why cppreference used that wording, I should have just looked it up in the standard myself.

Answer (score 6):

`random_shuffle` is being deprecated because its RNG is unspecified -- not just that *you* don't have to specify it, but that the standard itself doesn't specify it. On VC++, for instance, it uses `rand()`, which is implemented really poorly!

Comment: The fact that it's unspecified is what makes it better. `std::shuffle` is *worse* because you have to explicitly provide a specific algorithm, and most programmers aren't the best at choosing one - this task is much better left to the implementers. Also if you explicitly provide one, even if it's good, that means that it can't ever be changed to something better. If you don't provide one, then it could always be changed to something better.

Comment: @Neme it being unspecified means it is only useful when you don't care. Which is fine plenty of the time. But that shouldn't be mischaracterized as allowing the compiler to make a better choice than you -- don't leave things up to the unknown when they matter.

Comment: The majority of people don't care - they just want random numbers. Anyone who actually wants random numbers doesn't care. If they did care, that would mean they want a specific sequence of numbers, not random numbers - and the use case is to get random numbers.. –

Answer (score 5):

The other responses answer the question, but
if anyone is looking for some cut-n-paste code that may suit your needs, the following will probably do the trick:

```
#include <random>
...
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 g(rd());
std::shuffle(v.begin(), v.end(), g);
```

`rd` yields non-deterministic random data on many platforms and the generator `g` uses a [Mersenne Twister pseudo-random generator](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/mt19937/) with a large state.