# Using std::shuffle with custom Random Number Generator?

Tags: c++, c++11, random, std, shuffle

I see that `std::shuffle` takes an `URNG` argument.
I am using a custom version of a generator (WELL512a)  and would like to use it with `std::shuffle`.

My question is : Is it possible to use it with `std::shuffle`?
For example maybe by using URNG as a base class?

Comment: `std::suffle` have you tried `std::vol-au-vent`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`URNG` is the name of a template parameter - it's not a particular type. You need to implement an object that meets certain requirements, then you can pass it to `std::shuffle`. Something along these lines:

```
class MyRNG {
public:
  typedef size_t result_type;
  static size_t min() { return 0; }
  static size_t max() { return 42; }
  size_t operator()() {
    // generate a random number in the range [0, 42]
  }
};

std::shuffle(someVector.begin(), someVector.end(), MyRNG());
```

You may also consider using `std::random_shuffle` instead. That one takes an object `r` which can be called as `r(n)` for some integer `n`, and produce a random number in the range `[0, n)`.

<sub>**Note:** [`std::random_shuffle`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22600100/why-are-stdshuffle-methods-being-deprecated-in-c14) is deprecated in C++14.</sub>

Answer (score 6):

We can see from the cppreference documentation on [std::shuffle](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) that:

> URNG must meet the requirements of UniformRandomNumberGenerator.

unfortunately the site does not document what those requirements are, so we need to go to the draft C++11 standard section `26.5.1.3` *Uniform random number generator requirements* which says the following:

> 1. A uniform random number generator g of type G is a function object
>      returning unsigned integer values such that each value in the range of
>      possible results has (ideally) equal probability of being returned
> 2. A class G satisfies the requirements of a uniform random number generator if the 
>      expressions shown in Table 116 are valid and have the indicated
>      semantics, and if G also satisfies all other requirements of this
>      section 26.5.1.3. In that Table and throughout this section:
>
>    - T is
>        the type named by G’s associated result_type, and
>    - g is a value of

Table `116` is summarized as follows:

- G::result_type

  - return type is T
  - T is an unsigned integer type
- g()

  - return type T
  - Returns a value in the closed interval [G::min(), G::max()].
- G::min()

  - return type T
  - Denotes the least value potentially returned by operator().
- G::max()

  - return type T
  - Denotes the greatest value potentially returned by operator().

> The following relation shall hold: G::min() < G::max().

**Update**

To clarify when it says *T is an unsigned integer type* it means one of the following types covered in section `3.9.1` *Fundamental types* which include:

- unsigned char
- unsigned short int
- unsigned int
- unsigned long int
- unsigned long long int

This also include *extended unsigned integer* types such as *uinit64_t*, if your platform supports them.

Comment: Thanks! Out of curiosity, when they say "T is an unsigned integer type", does it means 32 bit only (on x86/x64)?

Comment: It documents it, briefly, on the same page ("function object returning a randomly chosen value of type URNG::result_type in the interval [g.min(), g.max()] if invoked as g() (e.g. any of the uniform random number generators from <random>)"), but yes, the actual type requirements is a redlink waiting to be filled.

Comment: @Yannick: **3.9.1/2** There are five *standard signed integer types*: “`signed char`”, “`short int`”, “`int`”, “`long int`”, and “`long long int`”... There may also be implementation-defined *extended signed integer types*. The standard and extended signed
integer types are collectively called *signed integer types*. **3.9.1/3** For each of the standard signed integer types, there exists a corresponding (but different) *standard unsigned
integer type*... Likewise, for each of the extended signed integer types there exists a corresponding *extended unsigned integer type*...

Comment: What I meant is. Since they state "T is an unsigned integer type", could T techincally be uint64_t for example, or is it just uint32_t that would be accepted there? Basically, "T is an unsigned integer type" is irrevelant to me, in the sense that it doesnt specify whether we can use "unsigned long long int" or if its only restricted to "unsigned int" :)