# How do I pass standard generators to STL functions?

Tags: c++, stl

```
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector < int > a = {1, 2, 3};
    std::mt19937 generator;
    std::random_shuffle(a.begin(), a.end(), generator);
}
```

I am trying to compile this code with g++ -std=c++0x, receiving a huge compiler dump ending with

```
/usr/include/c++/4.9.2/bits/random.h:546:7: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
```

Any way of doing it correctly?

Comment: Thx, worked like a charm. Could you post it as an answer in order for me to accept it?

Comment: You could use a wrapper function or lambda; the `RandomFunc` parameter expects something which will itself take a parameter `n`, and the C++11 random number facilities all have their range parameters baked into their instances. But chris' answer is best, of course.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The overload of [`std::random_shuffle`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) you're trying to use takes a "RandomFunc":

> function object returning a randomly chosen value of type convertible to `std::iterator_traits<RandomIt>::difference_type` in the interval [0,n) if invoked as r(n)

In C++14, `std::random_shuffle` is deprecated in favour of `std::shuffle`, which takes a generator rather than that "RandomFunc". Simply change the function to `std::shuffle`.

Comment: +1 [link the the why it is deprecated question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22600100/1708801).

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour, Thanks, I probably should have expanded on that a little bit.