# I'm making a BlackJack program. I have two problems at the moment

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017

Everything pretty much works now! Thanks for the help!

I have two problems at the moment - one is that when the dealer is picking an ace, it will display (through a cout) the correct value (1 or 11) depending on its current sum but it wont add to the cardSumDealer for some reason? Like if it picks its first card as an ace, it should change its value to an 11 as its sum is below 10 but it uses it as a 1. It always uses it as a 1.

My second problem is fixed. I made a mistake with my vector. My bad.

Apparently I need to shorten this. I will leave the main code below but here is the problem area:

```
//FIRST CARD FOR DEALER
        dealerCardOne = drawCard();

                                        //ace
                                    dealerOneVal = getCardVal(dealerCardOne);

                                    int ace1 = 0;
                                    if (dealerOneVal == 1)
                                    {
                                        if (cardSumDealer <= 10)
                                        {
                                            cout << endl << "The dealer chose 11" << endl; //REMOVE

                                            ace1 = 11;
                                        }
                                        else if(cardSumDealer > 10)
                                        {
                                            cout << endl << "The dealer chose 1" << endl; //REMOVE

                                            ace1 = 1;
                                        }
                                        cardSumDealer += ace1;
                                    }
                                    else
                                        cardSumDealer += dealerOneVal;
```

The problem here is that where ace1 should be added to the cardSumDealer, it always only adds 1 to it no matter if it couts that the dealer chose 11. I'm not sure what is going on.

```
#include <iostream>

#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0500

#include<fstream> //files
#include <cmath> //calculations
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdlib.h> //randoms
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h> //regulating time
#include <windows.h>
#include <vector> //vectors
#include <algorithm>// std::sort
#include <string>
#include <windows.system.h>



using namespace std;

HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE); //for handeling my colors

//COLOR FUNCTIONS
void whiteText(void) {
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, (FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_BLUE | FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY)); //Sets text color to white
}
void redText(void) {
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, (FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY));
}
void darkRedText(void) {
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, 4);
}
void greenText(void) {
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, (FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY));
}
void darkGreenText(void) {
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, 2);
}
void blueText(void) {
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, (FOREGROUND_BLUE | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY));
}
void yellowText(void) {
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, 14);
}
void titleText(void) {
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, 267);
}



//Initializing Functions
int drawCard();
void shuffleCards();
void fixCard(int randomfillervalue, int who);
int getCardVal(int randomfillervalue);
void title();
int aceControl(int a, int c);
int Win();
void Bust();
int Tie();
void Lose();
void compareHands(int ran1, int ran2);
void updateFile(int q);

//SETTING UP THE CARD VECTOR
vector<int> cards = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52 };
const vector<int> permCards = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52};

//global variables
int money;
int bet = 0;

//files
ifstream fin;//opening the input file
ofstream fout; //opening the output file

int main()
{
    //Console Size
        HWND console = GetConsoleWindow();
        RECT r;
        GetWindowRect(console, &r); //stores the console's current dimensions

        //MoveWindow(window_handle, x, y, width, height, redraw_window);
        MoveWindow(console, r.left, r.top, 800, 800, TRUE);


    bool run = true;

        char saveChar;
        char character;

        fin.open("SaveFile.txt");

        //WELCOMING
        system("CLS");
        title();
        cout << "Welcome to Blackjack! Press any key and 'enter' to begin playing." << endl;
        cin >> character;

        //REDRAWING THE TITLE
        system("CLS");
        title();

        while (run)

        {
            bool bettingBool = true;

            system("CLS");
            title();
        //READING SAVE FILE
        cout << "Would you like to use a previously save file and the money you made? If so, press 'y' and then 'enter'. If not, press any other key and that file will be overwritten." << endl;
        cin >> saveChar;

        //REDRAWING THE TITLE
        system("CLS");
        title();

        //STARTING BETTING
        if (saveChar == 'y') //accessing the savefile
        {
            fin >> money;
            cout << "You currently have";
            blueText();
            cout << " $";
            cout << money;
            cout << "." << endl; //getting the current amount of money from save file
            whiteText();
            fin.close();

            if (money <= 0) //preventing complete lack of money
            {
                cout << "You do not have enough money in this save file to continue. Resetting the file to $200..." << endl;
                money = 200;
                updateFile(money);
            }
            cout << "How much would you like to bet?" << endl; //asking for bet amount

            while (bettingBool)
            {
                cin >> bet;
                if (bet > money) //preventing over-betting
                    cout << "\nYou cannot bet that amount. Please enter another amount..." << endl;
                else
                {
                    money -= bet;
                    cout << "You now have";
                    blueText();
                    cout << " $";
                    cout << money;
                    whiteText();
                    cout << "." << endl; //printing out new amount of money

                    updateFile(money);

                    bettingBool = false; //exiting this while loop
                }
            }
        }
        else //if you do not access a save file
        {
            money = 200;

            updateFile(money);
            cout << "You currently have the starting amount of:";
            blueText();
            cout << " $";
            cout << money;
            whiteText();
            cout << "." << endl;
            cout << "How much would you like to bet?" << endl;
            while (bettingBool)
            {
                cin >> bet;
                if (bet > money) //preventing over-betting
                    cout << "\nYou cannot bet that amount. Please enter another amount..." << endl;
                else
                {
                    bettingBool = false;
                    money -= bet;
                    cout << "You now have";
                    blueText();
                    cout << " $";
                    cout << money;
                    whiteText();
                    cout << "." << endl;
                    whiteText();
                    updateFile(money);
                }
            }
        }

        //REDRAWING THE TITLE
        Sleep(2000);
        system("CLS");
        title();

        shuffleCards();

        Sleep(2000);
        system("CLS");
        title();

        cout << "The Dealer will now distribute two cards to you and two to themself - only one of their cards will be visible to you." << endl;
        Sleep(1000);

        int firstCard, secondCard, thirdCard; //player cards
        int dealerCardOne, dealerCardTwo, dealerCardThree; //dealer cards
        int cardSumPlayer = 0, cardSumDealer = 0; //player/dealer sums
        int cardOneVal, cardTwoVal, cardThreeVal; //player values
        int dealerOneVal, dealerTwoVal, dealerThreeVal; //dealer values

        cout << endl;

        //FIRST CARD FOR PLAYER
        darkGreenText();
        cout << "Your cards: ";
        whiteText();
        firstCard = drawCard();
        fixCard(firstCard, 1);
        cout << endl;
        //ace
        cardOneVal = getCardVal(firstCard);
        if (cardOneVal == 1)
            cardOneVal = aceControl(cardOneVal, cardSumPlayer);

        //FIRST CARD FOR DEALER
        dealerCardOne = drawCard();

                                        //ace
                                    dealerOneVal = getCardVal(dealerCardOne);

                                    int ace1 = 0;
                                    if (dealerOneVal == 1)
                                    {
                                        if (cardSumDealer <= 10)
                                        {
                                            cout << endl << "The dealer chose 11" << endl; //REMOVE

                                            ace1 = 11;
                                        }
                                        else if(cardSumDealer > 10)
                                        {
                                            cout << endl << "The dealer chose 1" << endl; //REMOVE

                                            ace1 = 1;
                                        }
                                        cardSumDealer += ace1;
                                    }
                                    else
                                        cardSumDealer += dealerOneVal;


        //SECOND CARD FOR PLAYER
        secondCard = drawCard();
        fixCard(secondCard, 1);
        cout << endl;
        //ace
        cardTwoVal = getCardVal(secondCard);
        if (cardTwoVal == 1)
            cardTwoVal = aceControl(cardTwoVal, cardSumPlayer);

        bool runResponse = true, dealerRunResponse = true; //booleans for running the hit or stay programs for both dealer and player
        //Beginning Sum
        cardSumPlayer = (cardOneVal + cardTwoVal);
        if (cardSumPlayer == 21)
        {
            money += Win();
            updateFile(money);
            cout << "You automatically win! Your new total money is:";
            blueText();
            cout << " $";
            cout << money << endl;
            whiteText();
            runResponse = false;
            dealerRunResponse = false;
        }

        //SECOND CARD FOR DEALER
        cout << endl;
        dealerCardTwo = drawCard();
        darkRedText();
        cout << "The Dealer's top card: ";
        whiteText();
        fixCard(dealerCardTwo, 2);
        cout << endl;
                                        //ace
                                    dealerTwoVal = getCardVal(dealerCardTwo);
                                    int ace2 = 0;
                                    if (dealerTwoVal == 1)
                                    {
                                        if (cardSumDealer <= 10)
                                        {
                                            cout << endl << "The dealer chose 11" << endl; //REMOVE

                                            ace2 = 11;
                                        }
                                        else if (cardSumDealer > 10)
                                        {
                                            cout << endl << "The dealer chose 1" << endl; //REMOVE

                                            ace2 = 1;
                                        }
                                        cardSumDealer += ace2;

                                    }
                                    else
                                        cardSumDealer += dealerTwoVal;
                                    cout << endl;


        while (runResponse) //While loop for controlling the hitting and staying
        {
            cout << "Your current total is ";
            yellowText();
            cout << cardSumPlayer;
            whiteText();
            cout << ". Would you like to 'h' (hit) or 's' (stay)?" << endl;
            char response;
            cin >> response;
            if (response == 'h')
            {
                thirdCard = drawCard();
                cout << "Your next card: ";
                fixCard(thirdCard, 1);
                cout << endl;

                    //aces
                cardThreeVal = getCardVal(thirdCard);
                if (cardThreeVal == 1)
                    cardThreeVal = aceControl(cardThreeVal, cardSumPlayer);

                cardSumPlayer += cardThreeVal; //cardsum

                if (cardSumPlayer == 21)
                {
                    Win();
                    updateFile(money);
                    runResponse = false;
                }
                else if (cardSumPlayer > 21)
                {
                    Bust();
                    cout << "You now have";
                    blueText();
                    cout << " $";
                    cout << money << endl;
                    whiteText();
                    updateFile(money);
                    runResponse = false;
                    dealerRunResponse = false;
                }
                else if (cardSumPlayer < 21)
                {
                    runResponse = true;
                }
            }
            else if (response == 's')
            {
                runResponse = false;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "You did not enter a valid response. Please try again." << endl;

            }
        }

        //while loop for controlling dealer cards after the first two
        while (dealerRunResponse)
        {
            darkRedText();
            cout << "The Dealer's first card: ";
            whiteText();
            fixCard(dealerCardOne, 2);
            cout << endl;

            cardSumDealer = (getCardVal(dealerCardOne) + getCardVal(dealerCardTwo));

            while (cardSumDealer <= 16)
            {
                dealerCardThree = drawCard();
                darkRedText();
                cout << "The Dealer drew another card: ";
                whiteText();
                fixCard(dealerCardThree, 2);
                cout << endl;
                                        //ace

                                    dealerThreeVal = getCardVal(dealerCardThree);
                                    int ace3 = 0;
                                    if (dealerThreeVal == 1)
                                    {
                                        if (cardSumDealer <= 10)
                                        {
                                            cout << endl << "The dealer chose 11" << endl; //REMOVE
                                            ace3 = 11;
                                        }
                                        else if (cardSumDealer > 10)
                                        {
                                            cout << endl << "The dealer chose 1" << endl;//REMOVE
                                            ace3 = 1;
                                        }
                                        cardSumDealer += ace3;
                                    }
                                    else
                                        cardSumDealer += dealerThreeVal;
                                    cout << endl;

            }

            if (cardSumDealer <= 21)
            {
                cout << endl << "The Dealer's total is : " << cardSumDealer << endl;
                dealerRunResponse = false;
                compareHands(cardSumPlayer, cardSumDealer);
            }
            else if (cardSumDealer > 21)
            {
                cout << "The Dealer busted. You win!" << endl;
                money += Win();
                cout << "You now have";
                blueText();
                cout << " $" << money << endl;
                whiteText();
                updateFile(money);
                dealerRunResponse = false;
            }

        }

        cout << "Would you like to play another hand? If so, please press 'y' and enter." << endl;
        bool endRun = true;
        cin >> character;
            if (character == 'y')
                run = true;
            else
            {
                run = false;
            }
            cards.resize(52);
            cards = permCards;
    }
    updateFile(money);

    system("CLS");
    return 0;
}

void updateFile(int mooney)
{
    fout.open("SaveFile.txt"); //saving the new amount to the file
    fout << mooney;
    fout.close();
}
void compareHands(int playerHand, int dealerHand) //compares the dealer and player hands
{
    if (playerHand > dealerHand)
    {
        cout << "You win! Congratulations!" << endl;
        money += Win();
        cout << "You now have";
        blueText();
        cout << " $" << money << endl;
        whiteText();
    }
    else if (dealerHand > playerHand)
    {
        Lose();
        cout << "You now have";
        blueText();
        cout << " $" << money << endl;
        whiteText();
    }
    else if (dealerHand == playerHand)
    {
        money += Tie();
        cout << "You now have";
        blueText();
        cout << " $" << money << endl;
        whiteText();
    }
}
int Tie() //activated in the case of a tie
{
    int returnAmount = 0;
    cout << "You neither win nor lose. It was a tie. You get your bet of $";
    blueText();
    cout << bet;
    whiteText();
    cout << " back.";
    returnAmount += bet;
    return returnAmount;
}
void Lose() //activated in the case of a loss
{
    cout << "You lose. Sorry." << endl;

}
void Bust() //activated in the case of a bust
{
    cout << "You busted. You lost: ";
    blueText();
    cout << "$" << bet;
    whiteText();
    cout << endl;
}
int Win() //activated in the case of a win
{
    int winningAmount;
    winningAmount = 2 * bet;
    return winningAmount;
}
void title()
{
    titleText();
    cout << "=======================================" << endl;
    cout << " _____ _         _      __         _   " << endl;
    cout << "| __  | |___ ___| |_ __|  |___ ___| |_ " << endl;
    cout << "| __ -| | .'|  _| '_|  |  | .'|  _| '_|" << endl;
    cout << "|_____|_|__,|___|_,_|_____|__,|___|_,_|" << endl;
    cout << "=======================================" << endl;
    whiteText();

}
int aceControl(int cardVal, int sum)
{
        cout << endl << "Would you like to use your Ace as a 1 or an 11? Type '1' or '11'." << endl;
        int aceValue;
        bool aceRun = true;
        cin >> aceValue;
        while (aceRun)
        {
            if (aceValue == 1)
            {
                return 1;
                aceRun = false;
            }
            else if (aceValue == 11)
            {
                return 11;
                aceRun = false;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "That is not a valid response. Please enter your answer again." << endl;
                return NULL;
            }
        }
        return NULL;
}
int drawCard()
{
    int returnValue;
    returnValue = cards.back();

    cards.pop_back();
    return returnValue;
}
void shuffleCards()
{
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
    cout << "Shuffling the cards!" << endl;
    random_shuffle(cards.begin(), cards.end());
    for (int i = 0; i < cards.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << cards[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
void fixCard(int cardVal, int who) //couts the face of the card
{
    string suit, number;

    for (int i = cardVal; i == cardVal; i++)
    {
        if (cardVal == 1 || cardVal == 14 || cardVal == 27 || cardVal == 40)
            number = "A";
        else if (cardVal == 2 || cardVal == 15 || cardVal == 28 || cardVal == 41)
            number = "2";
        else if (cardVal == 3 || cardVal == 16 || cardVal == 29 || cardVal == 42)
            number = "3";
        else if (cardVal == 4 || cardVal == 17 || cardVal == 30 || cardVal == 43)
            number = "4";
        else if (cardVal == 5 || cardVal == 18 || cardVal == 31 || cardVal == 44)
            number = "5";
        else if (cardVal == 6 || cardVal == 19 || cardVal == 32 || cardVal == 45)
            number = "6";
        else if (cardVal == 7 || cardVal == 20 || cardVal == 33 || cardVal == 46)
            number = "7";
        else if (cardVal == 8 || cardVal == 21 || cardVal == 34 || cardVal == 47)
            number = "8";
        else if (cardVal == 9 || cardVal == 22 || cardVal == 35 || cardVal == 48)
            number = "9";
        else if (cardVal == 10 || cardVal == 23 || cardVal == 36 || cardVal == 49)
            number = "10";
        else if (cardVal == 11 || cardVal == 24 || cardVal == 37 || cardVal == 50)
            number = "J";
        else if (cardVal == 12 || cardVal == 25 || cardVal == 38 || cardVal == 51)
            number = "Q";
        else if (cardVal == 13 || cardVal == 26 || cardVal == 39 || cardVal == 52)
            number = "K";

        if (cardVal <= 13)
        {
            suit = "S";
        }
        else if (cardVal <= 26)
        {
            suit = "H";
        }
        else if (cardVal <= 39)
        {
            suit = "D";
        }
        else if (cardVal <= 52)
        {
            suit = "C";
        }

        //actually drawing the cards
        if (who == 1)
        {
            greenText();
            if (cardVal == 10 || cardVal == 23 || cardVal == 36 || cardVal == 49)
            {
                cout << endl << " ____" << endl;
                cout << "|" << number << "  |" << endl;
                cout << "| " << suit << "  |" << endl;
                cout << "|__" << number << "|" << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << endl << " ___" << endl;
                cout << "|" << number << "  |" << endl;
                cout << "| " << suit << " |" << endl;
                cout << "|__" << number << "|" << endl;
            }
            whiteText();
        }
        else if (who == 2)
        {
            redText();
            if (cardVal == 10 || cardVal == 23 || cardVal == 36 || cardVal == 49)
            {
                cout << endl << " ____" << endl;
                cout << "|" << number << "  |" << endl;
                cout << "| " << suit << "  |" << endl;
                cout << "|__" << number << "|" << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << endl << " ___" << endl;
                cout << "|" << number << "  |" << endl;
                cout << "| " << suit << " |" << endl;
                cout << "|__" << number << "|" << endl;
            }
            whiteText();
        }
    }
}
int getCardVal(int cardVal) //gets the value of the card for use in blackjack
{
    for (int i = cardVal; i == cardVal; i++)
    {
        if (cardVal == 1 || cardVal == 14 || cardVal == 27 || cardVal == 40)
            return 1;
        else if (cardVal == 2 || cardVal == 15 || cardVal == 28 || cardVal == 41)
            return 2;
        else if (cardVal == 3 || cardVal == 16 || cardVal == 29 || cardVal == 42)
            return 3;
        else if (cardVal == 4 || cardVal == 17 || cardVal == 30 || cardVal == 43)
            return 4;
        else if (cardVal == 5 || cardVal == 18 || cardVal == 31 || cardVal == 44)
            return 5;
        else if (cardVal == 6 || cardVal == 19 || cardVal == 32 || cardVal == 45)
            return 6;
        else if (cardVal == 7 || cardVal == 20 || cardVal == 33 || cardVal == 46)
            return 7;
        else if (cardVal == 8 || cardVal == 21 || cardVal == 34 || cardVal == 47)
            return 8;
        else if (cardVal == 9 || cardVal == 22 || cardVal == 35 || cardVal == 48)
            return 9;
        else if (cardVal == 10 || cardVal == 23 || cardVal == 36 || cardVal == 49 || cardVal == 11 || cardVal == 24 || cardVal == 37 || cardVal == 50 || cardVal == 12 || cardVal == 25 || cardVal == 38 || cardVal == 51 || cardVal == 13 || cardVal == 26 || cardVal == 39 || cardVal == 52)
            return 10;

    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: 1>C:\cpp\boost_test\stackoverflow\code.cpp(559): error C3861: 'random_shuffle': identifier not found
Please update your code. And, you did not: #include <iostream>

Comment: @lakeweb The #include <algorithm> should allow for the use of random_shuffle ? It works on Visual Studio 2017 - i.e. the program runs - and #include <iostream> is at the top!

Comment: I'm using VS2019, I'll take a look.

Comment: *My second problem is that occasionally, after multiple rounds in the same console, I'll get an error (Debug Assertion Failed! ... Expression: vector subscript out of range..). Please help!* -- The error is clear, and the debugger even points you to the line that is causing the issue.  It's your job to correct the logical error.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie the debugger points to a line that is several thousand lines outside of what my code is?

Comment: @JackM Look at the call stack in the debugger.  Go to the function that you wrote that causes the issue.  Basically, you're asking someone to debug your program, and honestly, you should be doing the debugging.  Debugging is part and parcel of learning how to write programs.  See [this link](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: [random_shullfe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22600100/why-are-stdshuffle-methods-being-deprecated-in-c14) is deprecated. I'll use shuffle...

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I found what was happening - the card vector was supposed to be replaced with the permCard vector but was outside of the main while loop and as such each round was being depleted but still being expected to remain at a constant size by the program, hence the error. I appreciate your help though.

Comment: There is far too much code in this post. Please read [How to Create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and then [edit] your post to remove all of the code that is not needed to demonstrate the problem. Expecting us to read through all of your code to try to pick out the problem area isn't reasonable.

Comment: @KenWhite okay, sorry. I updated it with the snippet of code from where the problem arises but still kept the main code below. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Then you didn't read the link I provided. If you want help here, you should follow the site guidelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the "FIRST CARD FOR DEALER" and "SECOND CARD FOR DEALER" sections, `cardSumDealer` is incremented by an ace value of 1 or 11, but then, in the `dealerRunResponse` loop:

```
cardSumDealer = (getCardVal(dealerCardOne) + getCardVal(dealerCardTwo));
```

This line resets `cardSumDealer` so that each ace is counted as 1, regardless of whether the hand is soft or not.

Another gotcha is that you need to remember how many aces are in a hand in addition to the total.  If the dealer has Ace / 4, for a total of 15, and draws a ten, he doesn't go bust.  Instead, the ace counts for 1 now, and the total is still 15.